# Обработка JSON на андроиде

Tags: android, java, json, mysql

Я с помощью php-скрипта получаю данные. Код "приема" такой:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_students, "GET", params);
            Log.d("All", json.toString());//выводим весь список
            try {
                // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // Получаем масив из студентов
                    students = json.getJSONArray(TAG_students);
                    // перебор всех студентов
                    for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = students.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Сохраняем каждый json элемент в переменную
                        String fio= c.getString(TAG_FIO);
                        String group = c.getString(TAG_GROUP);
                        Log.d("All",fio);//Вывод в лог фио и группы
                        Log.d("All",group);//для проверки =)
                        Log.d("All","1");//начало "чекпоинта"
                        //txtFIO.setText(id);
                        //txtGroup.setText(name);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fio+group, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("All","2");//конец "чекпоинта"
                    }
```

В общем, не получается никак вывести значения переменных. Хоть в текстбоксы, хоть в тост. Просто ломается при попытке вывести, и в логКат ни ошибок, ни чего-то подозрительного. Если убрать вывод, то все элементы замечательно перебирает и все данные выводит в логе.

Лог перед крэшем:

```
02-25 19:27:33.451: D/All(19290): {"student":[{"Code_student":"111111","FIO_student":"Первый П.П,","Group_student":"ПЕ-11","Id_student":"1"},{"Code_student":"222222","FIO_student":"Второй В.В.","Group_student":"ВТ-22","Id_student":"2"},{"Code_student":"333333","FIO_student":"Третий Т.Т.","Group_student":"ТР-33","Id_student":"3"},{"Code_student":"444444","FIO_student":"Четвертый Ч.Ч.","Group_student":"ЧТ-44","Id_student":"4"}],"success":1}
02-25 19:27:33.451: D/All(19290): Первый П.П,
02-25 19:27:33.451: D/All(19290): ПЕ-11
02-25 19:27:33.451: D/All(19290): 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не нужно создавать 3 одинаковых вопроса.
2. В логкат должно все же что-нибудь вывести. Попробуйте на другом устройстве или эмуляторе. Еще просмотрите внимательно фильтр логката.
3. В каком потоке вы пытаетесь вывести тост или вывести текст в TextView? Если не в главном, то работать не будет. с UI можно работать только в UI потоке.